# How to start the Web UI of Chirpstack-Application?

Tags: docker, lorawan

OS: Windows 10 Pro

The whole setup for properly starting up the Web UI seems confusing to me.

There’s the [source code to the chirpstack-application-server](https://github.com/brocaar/chirpstack-application-server) and its finished docker image. Running `docker-compose up` at the source code directory starts all the necessary backend services, but not the UI. In the source code, there’s a section with the UI inside the /ui directory. Starting this through npm works up until after this console log:

> Note that the development build is not optimized. To create a
> production build, use npm run build.

After this I get this proxy error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /swagger/internal.swagger.json
> from localhost:3000 to http ://localhost:8080/. See https:// nodejs.
> org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information
> (ECONNREFUSED).

Then there’s the [chirpstack-appliaction from precompiled binary](https://www.chirpstack.io/application-server/downloads/). I started this one by first creating the config file chirpstack-application-server configfile > chirpstack-application-server.toml and then starting the executable ./chirpstack-application-server.exe. Here I just get a connection error to PostgreSQL:

> time=“2020-09-17T11:09:08+02:00” level=warning msg=“storage: ping
> PostgreSQL database error, will retry in 2s” error=“dial tcp
> [::1]:5432: connectex: No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it.”

So what am I missing to get the UI up and running locally?